# MinGW "stdio.h : No such file or directory"

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I am trying to use MinGW to compile a C program under Windows XP. The gcc.exe gives the following error:

**stdio.h : No such file or directory**

The code (hello.c) looks like this:

```
#include < stdio.h >

void main()
{
    printf("\nHello World\n");
}
```

I use a batch file to call gcc. The batch file looks like this:

```
@echo off
set OLDPATH=%PATH%
set path=C:\devtools\MinGW\bin;%PATH%
set LIBRARY_PATH=C:\devtools\MinGW\lib
set C_INCLUDE_PATH=C:\devtools\MinGW\include

gcc.exe hello.c 

set path=%OLDPATH%
```

I have tried the option **-I** without effect. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try changing the first line to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

without the spaces. It is trying to look for a file called " stdio.h " with a space at the beginning and end.

Comment: The space before the colon in the error message gives this away. OP, get used to being pedantic about spacing and punctuation!

Answer (score 2):

You should try to install MinGW in the default install directory (i.e. C:\MinGW) I read many times it was recommended to avoid problems. There may be a (wrongly) hardcoded path in gcc.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that main() should return an int:

```
int main(void)
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use

$ sudo apt-get install build-essential

to solve this problem